# Plugin version number after code rewrite

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am the author of a plugin available on WordPress.org. It has around ~2000 active installs and is currently built upon the [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate](https://wppb.me/).

I've since decided that my plugin does not warrant the extra code so I am moving away from WPPB and completely rewriting it with a simplified custom class structure.

The plugin will have the exact same functionality, and this code rewrite will not to be noticable by the end user.

If my plugin is currently at version 1.1.2, what would be the next semantic version number for the above? On one hand its a complete rewrite, on the other hand none of the features change.

Comment: This seems like it's a pretty opinion-based question, so I'm voting to close it. That said, my opinion is that, since you're rewriting it from the bottom up, changing your entire codebase, it's worth moving to 2.0.0. [SemVer](https://semver.org/) says a major version change (1.x.x -> 2.0.0) is when a major change to the API happens. You're changing the plugin's entire structure, even if you're maintaining the same functionality.

Comment: this is not awordpress specific quetion so kinda off topic.... that said, +10 for leaving the brain dead WPPB which is overly verbouse with no added value. As for semantic versioning, if a bug is not being fixed and no api change it should be 1.2.0 (third digit indicates bug fixes, first a user noticeable change, so only the second is left). For your own sanity you should not be tempted to stay with the same version number as you will have hard time to know which bug report relates to which code base

Comment: Generally I'd suggest asking about semver on stackoverflow, no WordPress knowledge is necessary to answer this, but I'd agree with the others, this is more of a discussion prompt, you might get some good responses but you wouldn't be able to mark a specific single answer as the "correct" answer.